# Amazon Cognito signing in - Sample code given

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

So I [downloaded the attached project](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample/Objective-C) and copied **the code to mine project**. This is what I did.

I replaced the following with the correct values. I created a `USERPOOL` in amazon cognito to get these values.

```
NSString *const CognitoIdentityUserPoolId = @"XXX";
NSString *const CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientId = @"XXX";
NSString *const CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientSecret = @"XXX";
```

My question is that once the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is executed it'll fire up the delegate method which is `-(id<AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication>) startPasswordAuthentication`. However, in my case it doesn't How can I solve this ?

`AppDelegate.h` Looks like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "AWSCognitoIdentityProvider.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,AWSCognitoIdentityInteractiveAuthenticationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
@end
```

`AppDelegate.m` Looks like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

//setup logging
    [AWSLogger defaultLogger].logLevel = AWSLogLevelVerbose;

    //setup service config
    AWSServiceConfiguration *serviceConfiguration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:nil];

    if([@"YOUR_USER_POOL_ID" isEqualToString:CognitoIdentityUserPoolId]){
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid Configuration"
                                    message:@"Please configure user pool constants in Constants.m"
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                          otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil] show];
    }

    //create a pool
    AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration alloc] initWithClientId:CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientId  clientSecret:CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientSecret poolId:CognitoIdentityUserPoolId];

    [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool registerCognitoIdentityUserPoolWithConfiguration:serviceConfiguration userPoolConfiguration:configuration forKey:@"UserPool"];

    AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool *pool = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool CognitoIdentityUserPoolForKey:@"UserPool"];

    //self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    pool.delegate = self;

    return YES;


}

-(id<AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication>) startPasswordAuthentication{
    NSLog(@"Came into this method");
    return _signInViewController;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By disabling the storyboard, you have removed the call to get a session for the user so the authentication delegate methods are not called.  Putting some code like this where that line of code was will get a session and trigger the auth flow:

`[[pool currentUser] getSession];`